# How to do a select statement on a stored procedure from .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures

How can i select certain columns from a stored procedure, lets say i just want 2 of the 10 columns
item and total sales.

```
 Dim reader As SqlDataReader
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yeartoget", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
            If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = "0" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "asofsales"
            ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = "1" Then
                cmd.CommandText = "asofnetsales"
            End If

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            GridView1.DataSource = reader
            GridView1.DataBind()
            conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the columns you want and turn off the autogeneration.

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="field1" HeaderText="First field to show"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="field2" HeaderText="Second field to show"  />
```

You could also read the results into a datatable and delete the columns you don't want or do it with linq but that's just overkill unless you need to fiddle with the data further before displaying it

Comment: is that the only way, because on runtime i change which columns i want to be seen  
 and if i did do it this way how can i dynamically change which columns i want to show

Comment: Then read into a datatable and delete the columns you don't want. Something like
myDT.Load(reader)
myDT.Columns.Remove("ColName1ToDelete")
myDT.Columns.Remove("ColName2ToDelete")
myGridview.DataSource=myDT
or do it with linq
Several different ways to do this, just depends which you're more familiar with

Answer (score 0):

In the grid view designer, turn AutoGenerateColumns off, and then add in each column that you do want in the gridview. Have a look at the [Gridview Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548005.aspx).

Comment: is that the only way, because on runtime i change which columns i want to be seen